# Applying Keras Model to give an output value for each row

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am learning keras and would like to understand how I can apply a classifier (sequential) to all rows in my data set and not just the x% left for test validation.

The confusion I am having is, when I define my data split, I will have a portion for train and test. How would I apply model to full data set to show me the predicted values for each row? The end goal I have is to produce an concatenate the predicted value for every customer in the data set.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('BankCustomers.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13]  
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13] 

feature_train, feature_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

sc = StandardScaler()
feature_train = sc.fit_transform(feature_train)
feature_test = sc.transform(feature_test)
```

For completeness the classifier looks like below.

```
# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", input_dim=11, units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(activation="relu", units=6, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(activation="sigmoid", units=1, kernel_initializer="uniform"))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(feature_train, label_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
```

The course I am doing will suggest ways to get accuracy and predictions for the test set like below, but not the full batch.

```
# Predicting the Test set results
label_pred = classifier.predict(feature_test)
label_pred = (label_pred > 0.5) # FALSE/TRUE depending on above or below 50%

cm = confusion_matrix(label_test, label_pred)  
accuracy=accuracy_score(label_test,label_pred)
```

I tried concatenating the model applied to both training and test data, but i then was unsure how to ascertain which index matched up with the original data set (i.e. I don't know which of the 20% test data is relative to the original set).

I apologise in advance if this question is superfluous, I have been looking for answers on stack and via the course but so far no luck.

Comment: Are `X` and `y` passed to `train_test_split` are pandas data frames?

Comment: HI @akilat90 thank you, yes, I have amended description to include them.

Comment: @akilat90 thanks that was spot on! The reason I want to use on train set as well is because the competition wants me to give predictions for all values.. weird I know lol!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize pandas indexes to sort your results back to the original order.

---

Predict on each `feature_train` and `feature_test` (not sure why you'd want to predict on `feature_train` though.)

Add a new column to each `feature_train` and `feature_test`, which would contain the predictions

```
feature_train["predictions"] = pd.Series(classifier.predict(feature_train))
feature_test["predictions"] = pd.Series(classifier.predict(feature_test))
```

If you look at the indexes of each data frame above, you can see they're shuffled (because of the `train_test_split`).

You can now concatenate them, use `sort_index`, and retrieve the `predictions` column, which would have the predictions according to the order that appeared in your initial dataframe (`X`)

```
pd.concat([feature_train, feature_test], axis=0).sort_index()
```